Why is curl not using php.ini settings for cURL on frankenphp (Caddy) Alma Linux 9?
The issue is on Alma Linux 9 using frankenphp (which is Caddy webserver with a built-in php module) where php -r 'print_r(ini_get_all("curl")); confirms that my curl config is being read. But the output from curl_get_info($ch) demonstrates different settings. Specifically the cainfo and capath is wrong.
Array
(
    [curl.cainfo] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => /var/lib/frankenphp/.local/share/caddy/certificates/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory/dev.sportch.co.uk/dev.sportch.co.uk.crt
            [local_value] => /var/lib/frankenphp/.local/share/caddy/certificates/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory/dev.sportch.co.uk/dev.sportch.co.uk.crt
            [access] => 4
        )

)
cURL Error: Could not resolve host: invalid-url.example.com cURL Error: Could not resolve host: invalid-url.example.com
cURL Info:
Array
(
    [url] => https://invalid-url.example.com/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.000134
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [http_version] => 0
    [protocol] => 0
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => 
    [appconnect_time_us] => 0
    [connect_time_us] => 0
    [namelookup_time_us] => 0
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 0
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 0
    [total_time_us] => 134
    [effective_method] => GET
    [capath] => /etc/ssl/certs
    [cainfo] => /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
)

